# python xml: xpath for elements with childer with specific attribute values

Tags: python, xml, xpath, robotframework

I need an xpath expression for the following:

All nodes with the tag "test" that have a child with the tag "status" that have an attribute called "status" with the value "PASS"

so with the xml below, I need to get the node with the id "s1-t1".  I should be able to modify this so that instead of Passed tests, I get tests with the attribute `[@status='FAIL']`.  I've tried a couple things to no avail:

- `".//test/[@status='PASS']"` returns nothing
- `".//test/[status][@status='PASS']"` returns nothing
- `".//test//[status][@status='PASS']"` throws a SyntaxError("invalid descendant")
- `".//test//status[@status='PASS']"` returns 2 status nodes (one for the test status and one for the keyword status)
- `".//test//status[@status='PASS']/../.."` returns the correct test node, but also the suite node

I'm not sure what to try at this point.  Here's the XML I'm working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot generated="20151111 16:29:28.630" generator="Robot 2.9.1 (Python 2.7.10 on cygwin)">
<suite source="/cygdrive/c/test/robot/thing.robot" id="s1" name="Thing">
<test id="s1-t1" name="Case1">
<kw name="Should Contain" library="BuiltIn">
<doc>Fails if ``item1`` does not contain ``item2`` one or more times.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>hello</arg>
<arg>hell</arg>
</arguments>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.689" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.689"></status>
</kw>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.689" critical="yes" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.688"></status>
</test>
<test id="s1-t2" name="Case2">
<kw name="Should Contain" library="BuiltIn">
<doc>Fails if ``item1`` does not contain ``item2`` one or more times.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>hello</arg>
<arg>elo</arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20151111 16:29:28.690" level="FAIL">'hello' does not contain 'elo'</msg>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.690" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.690"></status>
</kw>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.690" critical="yes" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.690">'hello' does not contain 'elo'</status>
</test>
<test id="s1-t3" name="Case3">
<kw name="Should Contain" library="BuiltIn">
<doc>Fails if ``item1`` does not contain ``item2`` one or more times.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>hello</arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20151111 16:29:28.691" level="FAIL">Keyword 'BuiltIn.Should Contain' expected 2 to 4 arguments, got 1.</msg>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.691" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.691"></status>
</kw>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.691" critical="yes" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.691">Keyword 'BuiltIn.Should Contain' expected 2 to 4 arguments, got 1.</status>
</test>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20151111 16:29:28.692" starttime="20151111 16:29:28.633"></status>
</suite>
<statistics>
<total>
<stat fail="2" pass="1">Critical Tests</stat>
<stat fail="2" pass="1">All Tests</stat>
</total>
<tag>
</tag>
<suite>
<stat fail="2" id="s1" name="Thing" pass="1">Thing</stat>
</suite>
</statistics>
<errors>
</errors>
</robot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
.//test[status/@status = "PASS"]
```

This is exactly *All nodes with the tag "test" that have a child with the tag "status" that have an attribute called "status" with the value "PASS"*.

Comment: `SyntaxError("cannot use absolute path on element")`

Comment: @ewok sure, added the dot.

Comment: `SyntaxError("invalid predicate")`.  I suppose I should also ask. I'm currently starting with `root = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()` and executing `root.findall()`.  will this work?

Comment: @ewok is this an `xml.etree.ElementTree` you are using? It has a [rather limited xpath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), switch to `lxml.etree` if possible.

Comment: yes it is.  Is there a way do it using `xml.etree.ElementTree`? I'll look into switching.  shouldnt be a problem, but just in case

Comment: @ewok I'm afraid that you'll have to loop over the `test` elements and check if there is a `status` element with a desired `status` attribute inside. Lmk if you need an example. Thanks.

Comment: `lxml` is still giving me a `SyntaxError("invalid predicate")`

Comment: nevermind.  I was still using `root.findall()` and I needed to use `root.xpath()`. thanks!